# Populate input values to show a full name using Jquery .keyup

Tags: jquery

I want to show a full name text from the values of first and last name inputs inside a `span`, tried to use `.keyup` but this only worked with first name.

*code:*

```
<input id="first_name" placeholder="First name"/>
<input id="last_name" placeholder="Last name"/>

<p>
  Full Name: <span id="fullname"></span>
</p>

<script>
    $( "#first_name" )
      .keyup(function() {
        var value = $("#first_name, #last_name").val();
        $( "#fullname" ).text( value );
      })
      .keyup();
</scrip>
```

How can I add first and last name input values, on change, inside the `span`?

Comment: Change `$( "#first_name" )` to `$("#first_name, #last_name")`

Comment: Right... Thanks @Pedram !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind the `keyup` event on both the input boxes. Plus, you aren't fetching the value of `#last_name` into a separate variable.

The following is a working example:

```js
$("#first_name, #last_name")
  .keyup(function() {
    var firstName = $("#first_name").val();
    var lastName = $("#last_name").val();
    $("#fullname").text(firstName + ' ' + lastName);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="first_name" placeholder="First name" />
<input id="last_name" placeholder="Last name" />

<p>
  Full Name: <span id="fullname"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works fine, I also added.keyup(); at the end to see the result right when the page loads and not only on change...

Answer (score 0):

Fetch values of both the inputs separately and then concatenate them with a space and set it as html of the span.

You should attack `.keyup` event handler on both the inputs. Otherwise typing into last name input wont change the text of span.

```js
$("#first_name, #last_name")
  .keyup(function() {
    var fname = $("#first_name").val();
    var lname = $("#last_name").val();
    $("#fullname").text(fname+" "+lname);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="first_name" placeholder="First name" />
<input id="last_name" placeholder="Last name" />

<p>
  Full Name: <span id="fullname"></span>
</p>
```